# Extremely simple RNN doesn't learn trivial function

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm pretty new to TensorFlow, I've been learning for the last few weeks, but this is the first RNN for me.

My intention would be to predict the next value of an extremely simple function, in this case a line.

I expected the loss to come very quickly down to 0, and the predictions to become exact. However, no matter what, the loss appears to be meaningless and it basically follows any data fluctuation (in this case, a line, it goes up and up).

I'm posting the whole code (brief and basic as it is) as I'm thinking that I'm either missing something really trivial, or I just misunderstood some key concept here.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

num_steps = 6
state_size = 4
batch_size = 5
data_width = 600

def get_next_batch():
    def f(x): return x*2.867

    for k in range(0,data_width,num_steps):
        rx,ry = np.zeros([batch_size,num_steps]),np.zeros([batch_size,num_steps])
        for t in range(batch_size):
            rx[t] = [(k+i)+(t*data_width) for i in range(num_steps)]
            ry[t] = [f(h) for h in rx[t]]
        yield rx,ry

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size,num_steps])
Y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size,num_steps])

rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(X,[batch_size,-1,1]),axis=1)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size,state_size])
rnn_outputs,final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell,rnn_inputs,initial_state=init_state)

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([state_size,1],stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1))

Y = [tf.matmul(p,W)+b for p in rnn_outputs]

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=tf.unstack(tf.reshape(Y_,[batch_size,-1,1]),axis=1),predictions=Y)

train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    f = np.zeros([batch_size,state_size])

    for batch_X,batch_Y in get_next_batch():
        e,f,_ = sess.run([loss,final_state,train_step],feed_dict = { X:batch_X,Y_:batch_Y,init_state:f })

        print(e)
```